# como sumar cantidades de lluvia por fecha

Tags: rstudio

hola amigos tengo un problema al intentar sumar una determinada cantidad de datos, tengo un base de datos de 10 años y necesito sacar la precipitación que hubo cada día por eso 10 años, y para eso tengo que sumar todas las cantidades de un día, lo que necesito sacar es otro dataframe donde me aparezca la fecha y la cantidad de lluvia por día

[image: en la imagen se muestra como esta acomodada la información la fecha viene junto con la hora en la que se tomo la medida de la lluvia]

[image: en la imagen esta acomodada la fecha por día, mes, año y hora, la siguiente columna muestra la cantidad de lluvia en ese día y hora]

Comment: Bienvenid@ a StackOverflow! Por favor puedes agregar lo que has intentado hasta el momento?

Comment: Perla, las imágenes no son la mejor forma de compartir los datos, por favor agrega una muestra en texto. Por ejemplo, agregando la salida de este comando `dput(head(df, 40))`, dónde `df` es el nombre de tu base de datos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usando como base el dataframe (df) que tienes puedes obtener esos datos agrupando las observaciones por día y luego haciendo una suma de la variable objetivo. Para ello se necesita que tu columna *date* sea de la clase `Date`.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(dia = as.Date(date)) %>% 
  group_by(dia) %>% 
  summarise(lluvia = sum(rain, na.rm = TRUE))
```